# What will happen if my Google's App Engine instance will try to make more than 100 concurrent connections to a MySQL instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

At the end of [this page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/quotas) there is a paragraph that says: "**Each App Engine instance running in a standard environment cannot have more than 100 concurrent connections to an instance**". What does it mean? If there will be an App Engine instance that reach that limit, will it get an error or it will just create an another App Engine instance? How can I avoid this limit?

Comment: Unless you have buggy software that fails to close connections or you are trying to do work in threads without connection management, you should never have that many connections open. This article might help you understand connection management. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-sql-for-mysql-connection-security-high-availability-and-failover/

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the article. I shouldn't have that many connections open even if there are 200 000+ active users per second?

Comment: Good luck getting that many users on one App Engine instance. Try thinking a few  dozen per second. With good connection management you only need one connection to a database.

Comment: @JohnHanley :) So, if there will be that many users, they all will be splitted automatically across new App Engine instances, correct?

Comment: The answer depends on how you setup scaling for App Engine. Edit your question with more specific details so you can get a good answer. Don't use comments to "chat". I recommend deleting this question, study my link and research a few more documents. Then create a question when you have a problem that we can help you solve.

Answer (score 1):

This limit is per instance, this means that each of your app engine instances has this limit and is independent.

Also App Engine instances are serving by default up to 10 concurrent requests, this can be changed to 100 but no more than this. Because of this the only way to be hitting this limit is if the app is buggy and is not closing the connections.

Also [Connection Pools](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections) are recommended to be implemented when connecting to Cloud SQL, this limit the total amount of connections from each instances which once again will reduce the chances to hit this limit.